# center arrow over img with css

Tags: css, image, css-shapes

I want to show an arrow over an image. This arrow should be centered every time.
How can I do it?

Here is my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mondy/86e0gg99/):

CSS:

```
.t1_img {
  background-image:url('http://www.4freephotos.com/medium/batch/Branch-of-acacia-with-flowers777.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
  height: 200px;
}
.t1_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60px;
  border-left: 40px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-right: 40px solid #cfcfcf;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
}
.t1_content {
  background-color: #cfcfcf;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="t1_img">
  <div class="t1_arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="t1_content">
    Textinhalt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="t1_img">
  <div class="t1_arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="t1_content">
    Textinhalt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="t1_img">
  <div class="t1_arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="t1_content">
    Textinhalt
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="t1_img">
  <div class="t1_arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="t1_content">
    Textinhalt
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this tool - it may point you in the right direction (please pardon the pun): http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the width of the arrow so if you put it left:50%; and margin-left:-30px; because its width is 60px it is centered everytime.
So add this

```
 .t1_arrow {left:50%;margin-left:-30px;}
```

[Your fiddle edited](https://jsfiddle.net/86e0gg99/9/)

Comment: But now i want to get a gray background left and right from the arrow.

Comment: I don't want to see the picture left side and right side of the arrow.

Comment: ok now it is as you want you can put a after and before pseudo-element to img container as the example . Check the code and tell me . https://jsfiddle.net/spyrosao/86e0gg99/13/

Comment: I changed some small things, and now it works fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following line:

```
  left: calc((100% - 60px)/2);
```

Where 60 px refers to the width of the arrow. This method is not supported by all browsers, unfortunately. For safety, add the following three lines to the .t1_arrow class:

```
.t1-arrow {
    left: 45%;
    left: calc((100%-60px)/2);
    left: -webkit-calc((100%-60px)/2);
}
```

Or you could use jquery to set the height after pageload:

```
$(function() {
    $(".t1-arrow").each( function() {
        var w = $(this).parent(0).width();
        $(this).css('left',(w-60)/2 + 'px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it centred horizontally, add the following to your Arrow's CSS;

```
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
```

Updated Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/86e0gg99/12/

Comment: I don't want to see the picture left side and right side of the arrow. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, im not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a picture of the solution, i'm looking for.
https://db.tt/1UFk3baW